# How to remove a specific entry from a number of entries separated by comma?

Tags: regex, csv, vim

I have some entries in a csv file like below

```
John, 20, LA, USA
Jane, 50, NY, USA
Jim, 38, PH, USA
```

How can I remove the second entry from all lines in vim editor so that it looks like the following?

```
John, LA, USA
Jane, NY, USA
Jim, PH, USA
```

Comment: Could this vim run a python code that does this?

Comment: `%s/\,.\{-}.,/,` also works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
:%s/^\([^,]\+,\) [^,]\+,/\1/
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with the following command:

```
:%normal! f,dt,
```